# Can the Least Squares Method be expressed as a convolution with a kernel?

Tags: laser, linear-algebra

Consider a laser line position estimation by fitting using the Least Square Method (LSM) and prove (or disprove) that it can be considered as a convolution with some function and finding the center by looking for the maximum (zero‐crossing by the derivative). What is the smoothing function?

The Least Square Method (LSM) is defined as:
$$\sum_i[S(x_i)-F(x_i,;a,b,\ldots)]^2=min,$$

where the fitting function is:
$$F(x;y_0,A,x_0,w)=y_0+A\cdot g(x-x_c,w)$$

The fit program will adjust all parameters, but we are interested only in x_c.

Hint: change sums to integrals in LSM description!
Relevant Equations  fitting function:

convolution:

Least Squares Method:
[image]
I started by converting the LSM from sum to integral form:
$$f(x_c)=\sum_i[S(x_i)-F(x_i,;a,b,\ldots)]^2tof(x_c)=\int(S(x)-F(x-x_c)^2dx$$

Since we are not interested in the other parameters (like offset), I assumed that they are fitted correctly and thus ignored them, turning $$F(x-x_c)$$ directly to $$g(x-x_c)$$

Then I expanded the binomial formula as following:
$$\int S(x)^2-2S(x)F(x-x_c)+g(x-x_c)^2dx$$

And used the linearity of the integral to isolate the part of the equation that doesn't depend on x_0:
$$f(x_c)=\int S(x)^2dx+\int2S(x)g(x-x_c)+g(x-x_c)^2dx$$

Hence, we have a constant q that isn't affected by the convolution:

$$f(x_c)=q+\int2S(x)g(x-x_c)+g(x-x_c)^2dx$$

The middle term is a convolution og the 2 functions. My idea was to disprove that a Kernel exists, because there is a term that doesn't depend on
, but this logic doesn't make any sense after thinking about it. I am completely stuck at this point, since I can neither prove nor disprove that the kernel function exists. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Might [math.se] or [stats.se] be better suited for this math/stats question?

Comment: probably. It's definetly physics, but you're right, the fact that we're dealing with lasers can be abstracted away to convolution math